# UIDatePicker 8 hour earlier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker, release-management

I was trying to build a datepicker program on iPhone. However, the time showed in text is earlier exactly 8 hour than the time I choose.
Here's the code.

"h"file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIDatePicker *datepick;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield; 
}
-(IBAction)button;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepick;
@end
```

"m"file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize datepick;

-(IBAction)button {
    NSDate *choice = [datepick date];
    NSString *words = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The date is %@", choice];

    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"the title" message:words
    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    label.text = words;
    textfield.text = words;
}
```

Comment: When you say it's not exactly? What is the output, and what is it that you expect? Likely you're looking for `NSDateFormatter` to format the date how you want it.

Comment: I choose date to be like June-7..., but June-6... is showed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert selected date to your local timezone

```
NSDate *choice = [datepick date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter new] autorelease];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mma"];

NSString *strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:choice];
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comments, nothing is wrong, its just showing a different Timezone than you expected.  NSDate to string by default goes to GMT/UTC time.

Use an NSDateFormatter to control the timezone being output: [Apple Documentation for NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter)